# Reverse AODV in NS2 with blackhole attack

Tags: simulation, ns2, blackhole

Hi everybody I am wanting to simulate the Reverse AODV protocol in NS2 with black hole attack. Can someone help me, many thanks

I don't know how to change the AODV code in NS2 to the Reverse AODV protocol